# Re-scaling X axis in imagesc plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have written the following code in Matlab to show different shades of color red. How can I re-scale all x-axis in sub-plots to 0-1?

```
% create a custome color map
map = zeros(11,3);
reds = 0:0.1:1;
map(:,1) = reds(:);
colormap(map);

figure(1)

depth = [1 2 3 4];
num_depth = length(depth);

for index = 1: num_depth    
    subplot(num_depth,1,index);
    step = 1/(2^depth(index)-1);
    A = 0:step:1;
    imagesc(A);
    axis equal
    set(gca,'ytick',[])
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However, `imagesc(x,y,C)` could specifies the image location. Use `x` and `y` to specify the locations of the corners corresponding to `C(1,1)` and `C(m,n)`.

```
% create a custome color map
map = zeros(11,3);
reds = 0:0.1:1;
map(:,1) = reds(:);
colormap(map);

figure(1)

depth = [1 2 3 4];
num_depth = length(depth);

for index = 1: num_depth    
    subplot(num_depth,1,index);
    step = 1/(2^depth(index)-1);
    A = 0:step:1;
    imagesc(0:1,0:1,A)
    axis([0 1 0 1])
    set(gca,'ytick',[])
end
```

the output is:

[image]